# Bentching gomel - time limit?

Tags: halacha, time, hagomel

We recite [*birchat hagomel*](http://www.berachot.org/hebrew/hagomel.htm) after 1. traveling over the ocean; 2. traveling over the desert; 3. recovering from a serious illness; and 4. being released from prison. (Whether other cases of salvation are also included is debated.) Is there a time limit on when to *bentsh gomel* (recite *birchat hagomel*)? Please cite sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found the answer on [halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birkat_HaGomel#When_it_should_be_said):

> Preferably HaGomel should be said within 3 days. If it can’t be done within 3 days it should be said within 30 days, and if it can’t be said in 30 says it should be said whenever one wants. [S”A 219:6, Mishna Brurah 219:20, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 61:2]

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43405&hilite=9ce123cd-ce3c-4087-aea3-4ad6c5591e73&st=%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%9C&pgnum=252