# Practical halacha on when to bentch gomel (not why)

Tags: blessing, hagomel

What are the preferred or allowable to times to bentch gomel, assuming you have had an experience that warrants it.

For example. which of the following is preferred or allowed:
1. After completing an aliyah in a morning minyan.
2. At some other time in a morning minyan.
3. At a mincha or maariv minyan.
4. In the presence of a minyan but not during davening.
5. Alone, if you are without fellow Jews for the near future.

Note: This question is broader than these related questions:
[Bentching gomel - time limit?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53243/bentching-gomel-time-limit) 
[What does one do when one needs to bentch gomel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/what-does-one-do-when-one-needs-to-bentch-gomel)

Comment: 6. With a Minyan including two Torah scholars. 7. With a Minyan and two Torah scholars in addition.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9531/759

Comment: The answer to [What does one do when one needs to bentch gomel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/what-does-one-do-when-one-needs-to-bentch-gomel) is number 1 if possible. Number 2 and 3 would appear to be the same.

Comment: But it's not properly answered there...

Comment: @Kazi then see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 2):

It is said in [Orach Chayim 219:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%92) (based on [Berakhot 54b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=54b&format=pdf)) that you should do it with a *minyan* ([Mishnah Berurah](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%92#%D7%9E%D7%91_%D7%95) allows the obligated person to be included) and two scholars. It is customary to do it at Torah reading, as there is a minyan already there:

> צריך לברך ברכה זו בפני עשרה ותרי מינייהו רבנן, דכתיב *וירוממוהו בקהל עם ובמושב זקנים יהללוהו.* ואם לא שכיחי רבנן לא יניח מלברך. ונהגו לברך אחר קריאת התורה, לפי שיש שם עשרה. ואם בירך בפחות מעשרה, יש אומרים שיצא, ויש אומרים שלא יצא, וטוב לחזור ולברך בפני עשרה, שלא הזכרת שם ומלכות:‏
>
> One should say this blessing in front of ten, and two of them are sages, as it is written: *Let them exalt Him also in the assembly of the people, and praise Him in the seat of the elders ([Psalms 107:32](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26a7.htm#32)).* [...] And it is customary to say it after the Torah reading as there are ten. And if he blessed before less than ten, there are some that say he has fulfilled [his obligation,] while others say that he hasn't fulfilled, and it is good to return and bless before ten [...].

There is a debate, whether the sages are in addition or not, Rambam in [Mishneh Torah Berakhot 10:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927678/jewish/Berachot-Chapter-Ten.htm) and [Kitzur Orach Chayim 61:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.61.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) includes them in the ten. It is preferable to say the blessing within 3 days ([Orach Chayim 219:6](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%95)). R' Ganzfried also records the custom of giving an *aliyah* to the obligated person (and *gomel* is said after the concluding blessing), but it's not necessary.